# Unable to change color for part of an object

Tags: objects, color, subdivision-surface

I am trying to set color to red for the lower spherical part of the object (shown in the picture). It seems that there is a strip of surface whose color cannot be changed despite being selected. Would really appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked normals?

Comment: overlapping UVs? Please show the settings (in particular Uvs, I think).

Comment: @Cloud_In_A_Bottle Yes, the normals of the strip are facing outwards, just like the other faces.

Comment: @lemon excuse me if I didn't understood correctly (I'm new to Blender), but I have attached the UV editor screenshot here. I cannot tell if anything is wrong from this.

Comment: ok, you have two materials. Part of the faces of the red sphere are assigned to the green material. In edit mode, select these faces and assign them to the red material. (nothing to do with UVs, finally)

Comment: @lemon That's what I did exactly. The problem is that the green strip cannot be assigned to the red material, for some reason.

Comment: If so, could you share your file? please use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @lemon Thanks! I have shared my file. Its at (https://blend-exchange.com/b/LY4S82oE/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to duplicated vertices, which make the wanted faces unselectable, except if *X Ray* is turned on.

To solve the issue, select all, merge by distance and assign the material again to the wanted faces.

Comment: It works like a charm!